# How to remove duplicates in a sql JOIN while getting multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My project is about a blog where people post articles and get awarded weekly according to the post reach for the last week and ads and so on ...

for a certain situation, I need a query that returns multiple rows from three tables, the problem is that when i use JOIN there are multiple duplicates and i can't seem to find a solution to remove them.

The tables are structured as follows:

**Table 1 : Users**

```
  ID      | Name      | Age

  1       | Mark      | 16
  2       | Michael   | 21
```

**Table 2: Posts**

```
 userID      | postID   | Title

     1       | A1       | Inflation : A simplified Approach
     1       | A2       | The "un-winnable" game of politics
     2       | A3       | What is Bourgeoisie ?
     2       | A4       | The radical views of Carl Marx
     2       | A5       | Anna Karenina, or the greatest novel in history
```

**Table 3: Revenue**

```
   userID     | weekRevenue  

      1       | $0.2    
      1       | $0.14       
      1       | $0.91 
      1       | $1.72 
      2       | $0.99
```

---

All I want is a query that returns the following:

```
 ID    | postID    | weekRevenue

 1     | A1        | $0.2
 1     | A2        | $0.14
 1     | 'Null'    | $0.91
 1     | 'Null'    | $1.72
 2     | A3        | $0.99
 2     | A4        | 'Null'
 2     | A5        | 'Null'
```

i.e. : return values from all tables without duplicating any value and without linking any field from the two tables but to the `ID` field in the `Users` table

is that even possible ? , if not, what is the approach to reach anything close to what I'm asking for?

My approach (which obviously failed) was to use `JOIN` and here is my query

```
Select A.ID,B.postID,C.weekRevenue
from Users A
left join Posts B
on A.ID=B.userID
left join Revenue C
on A.ID=C.userID;
```

and the return was :

```
 ID    | postID    | weekRevenue

 1     | A1        | $0.2
 1     | A1        | $0.14
 1     | A1        | $0.91
 1     | A1        | $1.72
 1     | A2        | $0.2
 1     | A2        | $0.14
 1     | A2        | $0.91
 1     | A2        | $1.72
 2     | A3        | $0.99
 2     | A4        | $0.99
 2     | A5        | $0.99
```

I also tried `Right JOIN` , `inner` and combinations of them with no significant change in the returned table.

any suggestion would be helpful, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the results in a "relational" format, because the columns in a row don't have a relationship to each other.  However, you can do what you want using `row_number()` and `union all`:

```
select id, max(postid) as postid, max(weekrevenue) as weekrevenue
from ((select id, postid, null as weekrevenue,
              row_number() over (partition by id order by postid) as seqnum
       from posts
      ) union all
      (select id, null as postid, weekrevenue,
              row_number() over (partition by id order by weekrevenue) as seqnum
       from revenue
      )
     ) pr
group by id, seqnum;
```